# Android multiplayer chess - how to handle server connection?

Tags: android, networking, google-cloud-messaging

Just for funsies I want to create a simple chess-like game on Android. It will be a multiplayer for 2 players, with the game session stored on a dedicated server.

I was wondering - how to handle server -> client connection? I need a real-time responsiveness from the client, i.e. after one player makes his move, the game will wait for the other player to make his move. As soon as he does, the game in player 1's device needs to instantly know of this move.

Is Google Cloud Messaging good for this type of action? Is it reliable in terms of delivery speed? Or is there a better technology for this kind of communication?

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing you use socket programming for, generally.  You keep a persistent connection between the clients and the server.  When a client needs to be notified, you just send data down the socket.  GCM here is kind of overkill, and may not be immediate enough.

Comment: How do Sockets in Android fare regarding the battery life? I can imagine them in 'real' responsive games like first-person shooters etc, won't having an open socket drain the device fast?

Comment: It will drain battery, although not as much as the display does (and I assume the display would be on while playing).  But you said you wanted realtime-  direct connection is the only way to get realtime.  How long are you ok with in lag between move and notification, since it seems you don't really want realtime?